# Openpyxl fill the cells with color through for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I fill up the cells by using for loop instead of repeating the code several times?

My code:

```
ws['A1'].fill = PatternFill(start_color = 'FFFF00',fill_type='solid')
ws['B2'].fill = PatternFill(start_color = 'FFFF00',fill_type='solid')
ws['C3'].fill = PatternFill(start_color = 'FFFF00',fill_type='solid')
ws['D4'].fill = PatternFill(start_color = 'FFFF00',fill_type='solid')
```

my expected result is:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `chr(64 + i)` to get the characters. `65` corresponds to `A`, `66` to `B` and so on.

[Here](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.html) you can find an ASCII table wih the associations number - character

```
for i in range(1, 5):
    ws[f"{chr(64 + i)}{i}"].fill = PatternFill(start_color = 'FFFF00',fill_type='solid')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x,y in enumerate(['A','B','C','D'],1):
    ws[f"{y}{x}"].fill = PatternFill(start_color = 'FFFF00',fill_type='solid')

# here y will go from A to D and x will start from 1 as declared in enumerate
```

This is how it will go:

```
for x,y in enumerate(['A','B','C','D'],1):
  print(f"{y}{x}")
A1
B2
C3
D4
```